# Inheritance - warning when shadowing superclass variable with same name

Tags: java

When using Java, is there a way to get a compiler warning (using Eclipse, if it matters) when a child class shadows a super class's instance variables by declaring another one of the same name? For example:

```
class A {
    String variable;

    A() {
        variable = "A";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int variable;

    B() {
        variable = 1;
    }
}

B b = new B();
System.out.println("Variable value: " + b.variable + ", " + ((A) b).variable);
// prints out: "Variable value: 1, A"
```

I'd like to be warned in `B` that variable already exists.

Comment: Why? if you make your fields private as you are supposed to, then it doesn't conflict anyway.

Comment: Just because it can be useful to know, at the prototype stage when I'm not writing full setter/getter methods for everything, as it can create unexpected bugs.

Comment: It's called shadowing, not overriding and yes there are options to warn against it.

Comment: @Robin Ah, yes "shadowing". I knew 'override' wasn't the right word, but the right one slipped my mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  In Eclipse go to

```
Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings
```

In that pane there is a subsection on **Name shadowing and conflicts** that contains the options you are looking for.

Comment: +1, i just tried it and it worked for me .. :P, but would it be considered overriding of variables ?? i think its considered more of shadowing than overriding, am i right ?